# Can I use USB headset with iPhone?

Tags: audio, usb, headphones, iphone

I have a USB headset. It works just fine on a PC or a Macbook without any install.

If I connect it to an Android phone with micro-USB port, via some micro-USB to full-size USB adapter, it doesn't work. It can even restart the whole phone.

For iPhone with the Lightning port, is it possible to connect a USB headset to it via some Lightning-to-USB adapter?

Answer (score 5):

I've tried the Apple USB -> Lightining dongle with USB headphones. It delivers audio from some audio apps, but not the phone. Even with the phone app, I can hear the dial tones, but not the conversation. The conversation comes out from the phone's speaker.

Answer (score 2):

If your USB headset uses a split between USB power and an auxiliary line for the audio input you can use a battery pack to power the headset with the USB cable and use the dongle that comes with the iPhone 7 to connect the audio output from your iPhone 7 to your headset. Otherwise if you rely on getting audio transmission through USB data you will be out of luck unless somebody makes an external driver dongle for the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

> For iPhone with the Lightning port, is it possible to connect a USB headset to it via some Lightning-to-USB adapter?

Yes.  I have done this myself using the Apple Lightning to USB 3 Camera Adapter.
https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter

I was able to use a USB audio adapter to plug in headphones.  I had no real need to do this but to prove it works.  I have other, more convenient, means to connect headphones to my iPhone.

It's called a "camera adapter" but it will work with a number of USB device types.  I tested it with mice, keyboards, and audio devices, they all work.  If the sound comes out the wrong audio device then selecting it manually will fix it.  Sometimes the iPhone will not switch to the headphones that were plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to connect a USB headset to an iPhone 7, but it will not work until the required USB drivers and the ability to install them are available, which will probably not happen.